# Change password if not the same as last 3 passwords

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make sure the user cannot change their password to one of their previous 3 passwords. I have a table with their passwords stored.

When they are trying to change it, I am selecting their last 3 password

```
SELECT old
FROM password
LIMIT 3
```

How do I compare `newPW` with these last 3 to prevent the user from changing the password to one of these?

Comment: can you add the full table structure please

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

`SELECT count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT old
    FROM password
    WHERE username = '<username>'
    ORDER BY id desc
    LIMIT 3
) WHERE password = '<newPassword>';`

If it returns anything other than 0, the password has been used in the last three attempts.

You may need to replace the ORDER BY to a column that you use. As well you'll need to change the query to the structure you have.

Comment: with no ordering there's no guarantee it'll be the most recent three passwords selected, and derived tables need aliases

Comment: If you're able to do this, you're storing passwords in a dangerously insecure manner. They should be hashed with a proper algorithm like bcrypt.

Comment: @ceejayoz I will agree but with the lack of information can't really give him an more information.